# Using JPA/Hibernate Criteria to pull between a date

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to using the following code to pull a list of Experience objects from a `MySQL` table. Each experience has a from `datetime` column and a to `datetime` column and I only want to pull rows where todays date falls in between the from and to.

I am using JPA 2.0 running off of Hibernate.

```
    Date currentDate = new Date();
    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Experience> query = builder.createQuery(Experience.class);
    Root<Experience> root = query.from(Experience.class);
    builder.between(currentDate, root.get("from"), root.get("to"));
    return entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

My issue is that `builder.between()` obviously wont allow me to pass a Date object.

Is there a better solution to my problem?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can pass it as a parameter:

```
ParameterExpression<Date> d = builder.parameter(Date.class);
builder.between(d, root.<Date>get("from"), root.<Date>get("to")); 
return entityManager.createQuery(query)
    .setParameter(d, currentDate, TemporalType.DATE).getResultList();
```

Note that in this case you need to specify desired temporal type.

Also you can rely on the database's current date: `builder.currentDate()`, `builder.currentTimestamp()`, etc

Comment: Thanks - that is perfect. My issue now is that for some reason root.get("from") is returning a Path object and not an Expression object?

Comment: @Christopher: `Path` is a subtype of `Expression`.

Comment: The returned objects from root.get() are of generic supertype object not Date. But the first parameter is of generic supertype Date. All three must have the same supertype. Any ideas?

Comment: @Christopher: In this case you need to specify property types explicitly, see code. Also fixed typo in the type of `d`.

Answer (score 11):

You're just missing the call to CriteriaBuilder.literal():

```
Date currentDate = new Date();
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Experience> query = builder.createQuery(Experience.class);
Root<Experience> root = query.from(Experience.class);
builder.between(builder.literal(currentDate), root.get("from"), root.get("to"));
return entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

Comment: This would be the perfect accepted answer as it is a pure JPA, thanks

Answer (score 7):

You should switch your arguments:

```
builder.between(root.<Date>get("dateColumn"), startDate, endDate);
```

Answer (score 3):

This link looks promising: http://www.javalobby.org/articles/hibernatequery102/

You can use the `criteria.ge("date", root.get("from"));` and `criteria.le("date"), root.get("to"));` to create the between claus

If those aren't available, then you might need to look into writing HQL.