# Add CriteriaBuilder.between(Date) to Predicate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am new to JPA

I am trying to query a table where my input date value should be between the startDate and endDate of the database record

I am trying to do:

```
List<Predicate> conditionsList = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
conditionsList.add(criteriaBuilder.between(inputDate, root.get("startDate"), root.get("endDate")));
```

I found the below solution from [Using JPA/Hibernate Criteria to pull between a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256561/using-jpa-hibernate-criteria-to-pull-between-a-date):

```
ParameterExpression<Date> d = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Date.class);
criteriaBuilder.between(d, root.<Date>get("startDate"), root.<Date>get("endDate"));
```

But how to set the Parameterexpression value to inputDate variable value before adding the CriteriaBuilder to the Predicate?

Comment: Can you show your root class?

Answer (score 18):

You can try this way.

```
    Predicate date =  cb.between(root.get("date"), dateBefore, dateAfter);
    predicate.add(date);
```

this way works for my case.

But for your case (using ParameterExpression).

```
    return entityManager.createQuery(query)
    .setParameter(d, currentDate, TemporalType.DATE).getResultList();
```

When you create the query you set parameters.
`currentDate` is your date,
`d` is **`ParameterExpression`** that you create before.

I prefer the first way, it is more intuitive and logical for me.

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
criteriaBuilder.between(criteriaBuilder.literal(inputDate),
                        root.<Date>get("startDate"), 
                        root.<Date>get("endDate"));
```

Answer (score 14):

Something like this should work...

```
List<Predicate> conditionsList = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
Predicate onStart = criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("startDate"), inputDate);
Predicate onEnd = criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("endDate"), inputDate);
conditionsList.add(onStart);
conditionsList.add(onEnd);
criteriaQuery.select(root).where(conditionsList.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));
```

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering whether builder.between(date) is possible through ParameterExpression or some other way possible

Comment: this does'nt work ...

take for example start_date = 2020 and end_date = 2022 and you trying to find it using the query in the question by providing the input 2021