# How to fetch today's date in CriteriaBuilder in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Star> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(A.class);
Root<Star> root = criteriaQuery.from(A.class);
```

I am already having MONDAY of the week and FRIDAY of the week and then check the today's date lies between MONDAY and FRIDAY of the week.

I have use before and after method thats not working for me.

Comment: just use new Date();

Comment: Refer This: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256561/using-jpa-hibernate-criteria-to-pull-between-a-date. Might be helpful

Comment: you said you already having Monday and friday. this information is stored in database. Monday and Friday is stored in in some columns like startDate and EndDate .
you want to check that if current date lied between these days ? Am i right ?

Comment: I am able to get current date now, Monday and Friday as well but problem is i am not able to compare and check whether current date lies between Monday and Friday.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. use `cb.currentTime()` or `cb.currentTimestamp()`

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Star> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(A.class);
Root<Star> root = criteriaQuery.from(A.class);
// Add this condition
List<Predicate> conditions = new ArrayList<>();
conditions.add(cb.equal(root.get("Your  time column name"),cb.currentTimestamp()));
cq.where(conditions.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));
Query query=session.createQuery(cq);
```

Comment: because this is comparison with current timestamp, not with date. Most probably OP search something like `where date(table.created_timestamp) = date(now())`